# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

Thia has eaten up my weekend I searched about it but their might be several problems that might be causing it, hope some one will help me out.

I am trying to create a many to many relationship via one to many and many to one relationship using third table but I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: PoojaFirstCategory, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(poojaPanditRelationShip)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:314) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:292) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:239) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:483) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1327) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1789) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    ... 26 more
2016/04/03 09:12:14,134 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-7) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:286) [spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) [spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: PoojaFirstCategory, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(poojaPanditRelationShip)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:314) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:292) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:239) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:483) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1327) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1789) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    ... 26 more
2016/04/03 09:12:14,135 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:286) [spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) [spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564) [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: PoojaFirstCategory, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(poojaPanditRelationShip)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:314) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:292) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:239) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:483) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1327) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1789) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
    ... 26 more
2016/04/03 09:12:14,540 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-7) Error listenerStart
2016/04/03 09:12:14,541 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-7) Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

My entities are :

```
@Entity
public class PoojaFirstCategory {

    private Long poojaFirstCategoryId;
    private String name;
    private String brief;
    private Set<PoojaPanditRelationShip> poojaPanditRelationShip;


    public PoojaFirstCategory() {
    }

    public PoojaFirstCategory(String name,String brief) {

        this.name = name;
        this.brief = brief;
        poojaPanditRelationShip = new HashSet<PoojaPanditRelationShip>();
    }




    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getPoojaFirstCategoryId() {
        return poojaFirstCategoryId;
    }

    public void setPoojaFirstCategoryId(Long poojaFirstCategoryId) {
        this.poojaFirstCategoryId = poojaFirstCategoryId;
    }


    public Set<PoojaPanditRelationShip> getPoojaPanditRelationShip() {
        return poojaPanditRelationShip;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "poojaFirstCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public void setPoojaPanditRelationShip(Set<PoojaPanditRelationShip> poojaPanditRelationShip) {
        this.poojaPanditRelationShip = poojaPanditRelationShip;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBrief() {
        return brief;
    }

    public void setBrief(String brief) {
        this.brief = brief;
    }

}

    @Entity
public class PoojaSecondCategory {


    private Long poojaSecondCategoryId;
    private Long TId;
    private String poojaName;
    private String name;
    private Integer experince;
    private byte[] photo;
    private Integer rate;

    public PoojaSecondCategory() {
    }

    public PoojaSecondCategory(String poojaName,String name, Integer experince, Integer rate) {
        this.poojaName = poojaName;
        this.name = name;
        this.experince = experince;
        this.rate = rate;
    }




    private Set<PoojaPanditRelationShip> poojaPanditRelationShip;


    public Set<PoojaPanditRelationShip> getPoojaPanditRelationShip() {
        return poojaPanditRelationShip;
    }
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "poojaSecondCategory" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public void setPoojaPanditRelationShip(Set<PoojaPanditRelationShip> poojaPanditRelationShip) {
        this.poojaPanditRelationShip = poojaPanditRelationShip;
    }
    public String getPoojaName() {
        return poojaName;
    }
    public void setPoojaName(String poojaName) {
        this.poojaName = poojaName;
    }
    public Long getTId() {
        return TId;
    }
    public void setTId(Long tId) {
        TId = tId;
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    public Long getPoojaSecondCategoryId() {
        return poojaSecondCategoryId;
    }
    public void setPoojaSecondCategoryId(Long poojaSecondCategoryId) {
        this.poojaSecondCategoryId = poojaSecondCategoryId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getExperince() {
        return experince;
    }
    public void setExperince(Integer experince) {
        this.experince = experince;
    }
    public byte[] getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }
    public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
    public Integer getRate() {
        return rate;
    }
    public void setRate(Integer rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

}
```

and my relationship entity is :

```
@Entity
public class PoojaPanditRelationShip implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private Long id;


    private PoojaFirstCategory poojaFirstCategory;


    private PoojaSecondCategory poojaSecondCategory;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "poojaFirstCategoryId")
    public PoojaFirstCategory getPoojaFirstCategory() {
        return poojaFirstCategory;
    }
    public void setPoojaFirstCategory(PoojaFirstCategory poojaFirstCategory) {
        this.poojaFirstCategory = poojaFirstCategory;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "poojaSecondCategoryId")
    public PoojaSecondCategory getPoojaSecondCategory() {
        return poojaSecondCategory;
    }
    public void setPoojaSecondCategory(PoojaSecondCategory poojaSecondCategory) {
        this.poojaSecondCategory = poojaSecondCategory;
    }

}
```

and here I am trying to populate some dummy data:

```
@Component
public class StartOnStartUp implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private TouristFirstCategoryRepository touristFirstCategoryRepository; 

    @Autowired
    private TouristSecondCategoryRepository touristSecondCategoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PoojaFirstCategoryRepository poojaFirstCategoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PoojaSecondCategoryRepository poojaSecondCategoryRepository;




    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent arg0) {

        PoojaFirstCategory poojaFirstCategory = new PoojaFirstCategory("StayaNarayan","SatayNarayan Ki pooja");

        PoojaSecondCategory poojaSecondCategory = new PoojaSecondCategory("StayaNarayan","Pandit Brij Bhushan",23,1000);


        PoojaPanditRelationShip poojaPanditRelationShip = new PoojaPanditRelationShip();
        poojaPanditRelationShip.setPoojaFirstCategory(poojaFirstCategory);
        poojaPanditRelationShip.setPoojaSecondCategory(poojaSecondCategory);
        poojaFirstCategory.getPoojaPanditRelationShip().add(poojaPanditRelationShip);

        poojaSecondCategoryRepository.save(poojaSecondCategory);
        poojaFirstCategoryRepository.save(poojaFirstCategory);

    }
```

I am also using hibernate property to create table based on entity classes

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="first.varanasi.erp" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put annotation mapping on getter (or field), not setter. So instead of this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "poojaFirstCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public void setPoojaPanditRelationShip(Set<PoojaPanditRelationShip> poojaPanditRelationShip) {
    this.poojaPanditRelationShip = poojaPanditRelationShip;
}
```

You should use this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "poojaFirstCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<PoojaPanditRelationShip> getPoojaPanditRelationShip() {
    return poojaPanditRelationShip;
}
```

HTH.